# SQL mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,boolean given

Tags: php, sql

El hosting de mi cliente, realizo actualizaciones de base de datos y en el sistema que le eh creado no se puede "visualizar" los datos (En la base de datos si están) , el problema le adjunto.

***Alerta que me sale en el error log :***

> [10-Jan-2019 15:22:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects
>   parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   /home/*********/public_html/******/includes/class.Conexion.php on line
>   18

Ahora entro a `class.Conexion.php` (Pondre todo la codificacion)

```
<?php

 class Conexion extends mysqli{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct('localhost','******','******','******');
        $this->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        $this->connect_errno ? die ('Error en la conexion') : $x = 'Conectado';
        unset($x);

    }
    public function recorrer($y){
        return mysqli_fetch_array($y);
    }

    public function recgrupo($y){
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($y);// este es el error aca

    }
    public function rows($y){
        return mysqli_num_rows($y);
    }
 }

?>
```

En mi localhost aparece todo normal por la base de datos, me comento el proveedor de hosting de mi cliente que debo cambiar la linea de programacion del lenguaje de bd, estaré muy agradecido por sus comentarios.

Comment: el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Muchas Gracias ahora lo edito

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Tu caso ha sido planteado decenas de veces aquí, [puedes echar una ojeada a todas las preguntas/respuestas parecidas a la tuya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqli_fetch_assoc%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli_result%2C+boolean+given)  ese error ocurre porque el valor que le pasas a `mysqli_fetch_assoc` es un valor booleano (por lo general `false` porque algo salió mal en la consulta), cuando esa función espera un conjunto de resultados válido para ser leídos. Debes revisar entonces qué salió mal en tu consulta que hace que `$y` sea `false`

Comment: Ya esta actualizado mi pregunta , espero sus comentarios